# Create Root domain in OpenLDAP through command line

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to create a second root domain in OpenLDAP. I want to accomplish this through the command line. I understand that we have to edit the slapd.conf file and add the following for the second domain:

```
database    bdb
suffix      "dc=newdomain,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
rootpw          secret
directory   <path_to_preexisting_directory>
```

After this, I restarted the server, but the domain doesn't seem to get added as neither can I connect to it nor can I execute any commands such as ldapadd, ldapsearch etc.

What can I do to create the domain?

Comment: You need to run slap index any time you change a database.

Answer (score 0):

According to [openldap quick start guide](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html) #8 you don't have to change the ldap.conf, but you have to create an auxilliary .ldif-file and to perform ldapadd upon it:

```
#example .ldif-file for domain example.com
dn: olcDatabase=bdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: bdb
OlcDbMaxSize: 1073741824
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
olcRootPW: secret
olcDbDirectory: /usr/local/var/openldap-data
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
```

Call it, for example, test.ldif and use this command to add it to your database:

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w <password> -H ldap:// -f test.ldif
```

`cn=admin` can not work for you, it depends on how did you called your user

`-w <password>` is where you need to specify your password, without <>

I guess you would want to know, that configuring OpenLDAP with slapd.conf is *deprecated* and soon will not be supported. Using new method with ldif-files and cn=config has many pros, for example you don't need to restart the server after changing system databases.

Using `bdb` and `hdb` is also undesirable, they use Oracle BerkleyDB and OpenLDAP wants to go further with their own DB-backend, the `mdb`.

Comment: This answer only works if you are already using online configuration, which isn't mentioned in the question.